# Copper-core PCB with BGA: X-Ray inspection?

Tags: pcb, bga

When mounting BGAs, X-Ray is necessary for inspection of the ball soldering.
But what if I have a BGA on a copper-core PCB? 
Are there exisiting inspection systems covering this?
Or would I have to cut out the copper under the area of the BGA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-ray will easily see right through the copper.

This is an X-ray image of a BGA on an 18 layer board that has 6 planes:

[image: BGA X-ray image]

As you can see, the solder balls are clearly visible.

Comment: Ok... thank you! Meanwhile I did some research and found a calculator confirming what you say. Before  I'd expected the attenuation to be much higher than "almost nothing"...